# how to self-hosting a website on ubuntu 18.04 system and using lampp server?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, self-hosting, lampp

I'm trying to self hosting a website on ubuntu 18.04 system and using lampp server. i can not access the site through my public ip address. can anyone help me out?

i have also created a virtual server in my router. but till something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by logging into the router which provides you the internet …
then make port forward to all the requests that coming from external under port 80 ( which is the http browsing port ) and forward it to the IP which has your ubunto OS …
you may as well add RDP connection if you have windows , in short , you will have to find the responsible port which works for each protocol and then forward it to your ubunto OS 
like https , will work under 443 so you may as well forward it if you wan your website to work securely as https .

as for the domain name … you may use services fore free like DYN.com or noip.com

some routers btw can accept logins directly from dyn and noip and other similar websites which provide the dynamic hosting service .